# Is there a word for average but with multiplication instead of addition?

Tags: average

I came across a problem where I find the volume of a pyramid through `(length * width * height) / 3`. I noticed that there are **three** numbers being **multiplied** by each other, then divided by **three**. This reminded me of `Average` where you `add` numbers together then `divide` by the number of numbers that were `added` together.

Is there a word used to describe `Average` with **multiplication** instead of `addition`? And if so, what is it?

Comment: That's not really a meaningful averaging operation. There is something called the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an average of three numbers $x,y,z$ that involves multiplying them, but $\frac{xyz}{3}$ is not it. An average of three values should have the same units as those values; if $x,y,z$ were measured in meters, then $\frac{xyz}{3}$ would be measured in cubic meters. The correct operation to apply after multiplying three numbers to take an average is to take the cube root. $\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ is an average of three numbers known as the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).

If you are computing $\frac{\text{length} \cdot \text{width} \cdot \text{height}}{3}$, you are probably not computing the volume of a cube, but of a pyramid with a rectangular base. However, the geometric mean of length, width, and height does have a geometric meaning. If we have a rectangular prism that's $x$ by $y$ by $z$, then its volume is the same as the volume of a cube with side length $s = \sqrt[3]{xyz}$, so in this sense $s$ is the "average side length" of the rectangular prism.

Comment: (+1). Dimensionality / homogeneity reasoning is always really nice.

Comment: Oh and sorry, I meant square pyramid not a cube.

Comment: Does this work for percentages? Like 100 would be the "average" of 50 and 200

Comment: @Rivenfall Yes, you can say that the *geometric* average of $50\%$ and $200\%$ is $100\%$. (But you have to be careful, because even when percentages are multiplicative, we can do weird things with them. For example, to find the geometric average of a $50\%$ increase and a $200\%$ increase, we take $\sqrt{1.5 \cdot 3} \approx 2.12$, which we call approximately a $112\%$ increase. "If your stock increases by $50\%$ in January and by $200\%$ in February, the average increase per month was by $112\%$.")